# py2exe - MSVCR90.dll

Tags: python, py2exe, msvcr90.dll

I am trying to build a Python program with py2exe. I am getting this error when trying to run the built program:

```
The program can't start because MSVCR90.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I already installed the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package, NOT the SP1 version. What gives??

Answer (score 0):

Look at this response from 
https://superuser.com/questions/351609/how-can-i-fix-a-missing-msvcr90-dll-file-error

```
Just when I thought I was going to have to wipe the computer and reinstall everything to fix the problem, I decided to uninstall applications one at a time to see if one was conflicting.
 I uninstalled these apps...
 Zetafax Client Applications
 Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition Runtime
 Microsoft Silverlight
 I then performed yet another repair on Office Home and Business 2010, rebooted and voila - Excel is working again.
 I've since reinstalled Zetafax Client Applications and Microsoft Silverlight with all the latest Windows Updates and Excel is still working.
 I think the conflict was with "Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office Second Edition Runtime", though I've no idea which application installed this in the first place.
 Problem solved.
 This issue now appears to have been solved with a Windows Update. We encountered the same issue again with another machine. Uninstalling the apps listed here and repairing Office didn't help, but running the latest batch of updates that came out on Tuesday 14th February 2012 seems to have fixed the issue.
```

Comment: I will try installing/uninstalling to see. Possible confilcta would include VS Express 2010 and 2012, along with Office 2013 Preview(I still need to resave my documents).